# Are contacts from the Google account also stored on the phone?

Tags: contacts, offline

Are contacts stored in *Google Contacts* also stored on the phone or are they only accessible if the phone has a data connection?

Comment: Why don't you try putting the phone into Airplane mode and seeing if the contacts are still there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A copy is locally stored, so these contacts are also available when there is no current data connection.